# Assign hotkeys to windows (and remember size & location). AHK

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have found the following script for dynamically assigning hotkeys to already open windows:

```
Code (Expand):
Loop 10
{
   i := A_Index - 1
   HotKey #^%i%,DynHotkey
   HotKey #%i%, DynHotkey
   HotKey #!%i%,DynHotkey
}
Exit

DynHotkey:
   StringRight i, A_ThisHotKey, 1
   StringMid what,A_ThisHotKey, 2, 1
   var := var%i%
   IfEqual what, ^, WinGet var%i%, ID, A  ; Save ID
   Else IfEqual what,!, WinMinimizeAll    ; MinimizeAll
   WinRestore  ahk_id %var%
   WinActivate ahk_id %var%               ; Switch
Return
```

(the code was copied from this thread http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic38773.html&highlight=dynamic+hot+key)

With the above script you can:

1. Use Win+Ctrl+0..9 to **attach** hotkey to current active window.
2. Use Win+0..9 to **switch** to correspoding window.

However, if I assign a hotkey to a given window (using Win+Ctrl+0..9), and then I want I want to go back to that window (Win+0..9), the window is reset to a new size & location.

Is there way of **saving the size & location of the window** along with it's ID?

If so, what would the script look like?

I am running the above script on Windows 7 64-bit.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to complicate the code :)

Quick question: if your window is minimized you dont have any problems right?
The "problem" on the code is the `WinRestore`.

The thing is that if the window is not minimized and then you do a `WinRestore` it will change the size and position to the "not maximized" version of it.

WinActivate automatically does a WinRestore only if the window is minimized, so you can safely remove line 16 (the WinRestore one) since WinActivate will do what you need.

--edit--

this is how the code should look:

```
Loop 10
{
    i := A_Index - 1
    HotKey #^%i%,DynHotkey
    HotKey #%i%, DynHotkey
    HotKey #!%i%,DynHotkey
}
Exit

DynHotkey:
    StringRight i, A_ThisHotKey, 1
    StringMid what,A_ThisHotKey, 2, 1
    var := var%i%
    IfEqual what, ^, WinGet var%i%, ID, A  ; Save ID
    Else IfEqual what,!, WinMinimizeAll    ; MinimizeAll
    WinActivate ahk_id %var%               ; Switch
Return
```

I tested it, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinGetPos to read the actual position and save it. Then you can use WinMove to set the position. Here is a function list: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands.htm.